# How to attach ATMEL development board to VirtualBox VM?

Tags: linux, usb, virtualbox, virtualization

I have an ATMEL QT600 development board. I used VirtualBox to create a virtual machine with Windows XP SP3 and installed all the development tools provided by ATMEL. In order to program the board, I need to attach it to the virtual machine. However, the base device never allows me that option. It clearly shows in lsusb:

```
$lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03eb:2114 Atmel Corp.
```

But when I use VirtualBox it doesn't show it:

```
$VBoxManage list usbhost
Host USB Devices:

<none>
```

One way to proceed is to install Windows as the host OS but I don't want to do that. Is there any way I can achieve this? My host OS is Debian Wheezy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install [Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp11577648) and then allow USB from the settings.

Comment: Ofcourse I have already installed Guest Addons for VirtualBox. Didn't work. I also installed VirtualBox extension pack too. Still an issue.

Comment: @Karan no, maybe next time

Comment: i connected my arduino to the Vbox with ubuntu as base system, so i thought it might be the same